# Error while using child component in parent component - Angular 2 Unit Testing (KarmaJasmine)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

`template parse error` when using child component in parent.

I have two components.

```
  1. CardComponent
  2. InfoComponent
```

My CardComponent's HTML

```
     <div class="footer">
       <full-info></full-info>
     </div>
```

CardComponent's Spec File:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [InfoComponent, CardComponent ],
  imports: [
      FormsModule,
      MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ], //Used CUSTOM_ERRORS_SCHEMA also
})
.compileComponents();
  }));
```

My InfoComponent ts code:

```
   import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';


   @Component({
            selector: 'full-info',
            templateUrl: './full-info.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./full-info.component.css']
            })

   export class InfoComponent {
     public fullInfo;
    }
```

InfoComponent spec declaration:

```
     beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ InfoComponent ],
  imports: [
      FormsModule,
      MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
.compileComponents();
   }));
```

When I run test case for these two components **individually** then it is working fine.

When I am running these test cases at a time then I am getting error:

```
    'full-info' is not a known element:
1. If 'full-info' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'full-info' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    [ERROR ->]<full-info></full-info>
  </div>
```

I have imported `InfoComponent` in `CardComponent` even then I am getting this error. I am not able to find the issue. I any one knows then it would be great for me.

Comment: From what I see, you can individually test `CardComponent` and `InfoComponent`. Meaning that within your `InfoComponent` unit test you asure that `InfoComponent` is working as intended. Then, in your `CardComponent` test you asure that `CardComponent` is working as intended. Why test them together? I mean, when you are testing `CardComponent` you should have already tested `InfoComponent`, right? Therefore, if the unit test of each one of them passes, then they are both correct, no?

Comment: @SrAxi Testing individually means i testing using `fdescribe` on each. When I remove `fdescribe` then I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do both components share the exact same Module? 
Is the module imported well?
Is `forRoot()` extrictly necessary?

From [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root):

> Call forRoot only in the root application module, AppModule. Calling
>   it in any other module, particularly in a lazy-loaded module, is
>   contrary to the intent and can produce a runtime error.
>
> Remember to import the result; don't add it to any other @NgModule
>   list.

Try removing `forRoot()` and see if the error persists.

Hope I was of help, let me know how it goes!